# Spring webflux session management

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-webflux, spring-session

I am using Spring boot 2 with spring webflux running on netty.

I would like to add session management without needing to have a backing database or redis server (so Spring Session doesn't seem to be a solution here).

I could use WebSession in my controllers, but then I would need to enable sticky sessions on my load balancer, which I would prefer to avoid.

What I would like is one of the following:

- Client side session like in Play framework (session is stored as a cookie and added onto each subsequent request)
- [Hazelcast session replication](https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/web-session-clustering/gen-rep/) but this only works with servlet containers

Has anyone experienced the same thing and found a viable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Session has plans for providing Hazelcast implementation of `ReactiveSessionRepository`. The current plan is to wait for Hazelcast 4.0, which will move to Java 8 as baseline and use `CompletableFuture` instead of their own `ICompletableFuture`. You can track [gh-831](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/831) for progress on this topic.

In the meanwhile you could try and use `ReactiveMapSessionRepository`, passing in Hazelcast's `IMap`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.